# Assistance with installing gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have never installed gulp before, but I am trying to do so now. I am trying to follow along with a tutorial and already have the gulpfile.js (I downloaded the file from github, following the instructions from the tutorial) in a folder on my desktop with other necessary files for the project I am trying to create. I tried installing gulp globally while following the video. After inputting the commands, everything seems to be fine until I try the gulp command, which returns gulpfile not found. I then tried to use the command touch gulpfile.js and it says I have another error: the defaults are not found (or something along those lines). I removed gulp since I feel a screwed something up. Could someone walk me through how to install gulp if I already have the gulpfile on my desktop in a folder? I already have node installed. I am on a mac and am a complete newb at all of this stuff. All help much appreciated.

Comment: As your question is currently written, it's hard to guess what steps you've taken exactly. Please follow the guide at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

you have to put gulpfile.js in a project not in your desktop.

1. create new folder called "app"
2. open terminal and and run the command `cd app`
3. `npm init`
4. `npm install gulp-cli -g`
5. `npm install gulp -D`
6. create gulpfile.js in the app folder or run the command `touch gulpfile.js`.
7. now you need to install new plugins like `gulp-uglify` if you want to minify your javascript files.

8.run the command `npm install gulp-uglify` to install this plugin.

9.open the `gulpfile.js` on copy this code below :

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

// Include Our Plugin
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

// uglify Task
gulp.task('lint', function() {
    return gulp.src('js/*.js')
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dist('js/dist'));
});
gulp.task('default', ['uglify']);
```

9. create two new folders `/js` and `/js/dist` in the app folder.
10. in `/js` folder create your javascript file the will be minified.
11. run the command `gulp` in your app folder, your file will be minified in 'js/dist';